# plotting excel data in matlab

Tags: matlab

Okay, so i have compiled and done the calculations of a given data on excel spreedsheet. Now, because the data is so large, I want to use matlab to plot it. So, i separated each data set from 1-10 and saved them as txt files on a folder. I would like to use a code to assign some of the columns into column 1 and 2 and so on, say from set 2 for instance, and plot them. How should i approach it? I am currently using "importdata" code. How do i select the column i need in particular? Here is a sample of what i have so far:

```
set2=importdata(file2.txt)

column3=set2(?) (say i need column 3)

column4=set2(?)  (say i need column 4)

plot(column3,column4)
```

I'm not good at matlab. I would like some help. Thanks

```
set2 data saved as file2

350 1.2 858  0.02   1300        
550 1.4 721  0.02   1300            
650 1.8 673  0.02   1300                
750 2.2 600  0.01   1300
```

Comment: `set2(:,3)` says get all the rows (`:`) and the third column

Answer (score 3):

Note that you could just use MATLAB's built-in xlsread() function for reading data, rather than saving to text file and then loading. Extracting the columns would still be the same as the previous poster's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 column2 = set2(:,2)
 column3 = set2(:,3)
```

etc